# Header em uma Requisição http.send

Tags: asp.net-web-api, flutter, dart

tenho uma requisição por stream que é a seguinte.

```
Future<Stream<Chamado>> getChamado() async{
final String url = 'www.api'
final client = new http.Client();
final streamRest = await client.send(
      http.Request('get',Uri.parse(url))
      );
 return streamRest.stream
  .transform(utf8.decoder)
  .transform(json.decoder)
  .expand((data) => (data as List))
  .map((data) => Chamado.fromJSON(data));
}
```

Como que eu faço para colocar um header nessa requisição, usando o `client.send` sem ser `client.get`? tem como ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe `Request` possui os [headers](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Request-class.html) como atributo, basta criá-la e adicionar esses parâmetros no `Map`.

```dart
final request = http.Request('get', Uri.parse('url'));
request.headers['nome'] = 'parâmetro';
request.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] = 'Basic ${token}';

final client = http.Client();
final stream = await client.send(request);
```

Tendo o `request` preenchido, basta utilizar o `client` e `client.send()` conforme você já está fazendo.

Comment: A única coisa que modifiquei para dar certo foi o header da autorização.

Invés de :
`request.headers[HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader] = 'Basic ${token}';`

Coloquei :
`request.headers['Authorizarion'] = 'Bearer ${token}';`